# Better way to clean <label for= > with many options?

Tags: html, coding-style

I have this  with many options on it, i have nearly 30, i would love to know if another way can be used to make him more readable ?

Thank you.

```
<p>
    <label for="subject">subject :</label>
    <select id="subject" name="subject">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Have you used any [`optgroup` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/optgroup)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTML5, the closing tag for the  element is optional if it's followed by another option tag, or if it's the last element of the  element.

> An option element’s end tag may be omitted if the option element is
>   immediately followed by another option element, or if it is
>   immediately followed by an optgroup element, or if there is no more
>   content in the parent element.

So you can write it like this to be more readable

```
<p>
    <label for="subject">subject :</label>
    <select id="subject" name="subject">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
        <option value="">
    </select>
</p>
```

As far as I know this is also true for HTML 4.